# function does not recognize

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, ecmascript-6

**What am I trying to do:**

I'm trying to encode Flappy Bird with the p5.js library.

---

**Problem:** The function does not recognize the function I defined.

---

```
function Game() {

  this.pipes = generatePipes();
  setInterval(this.gameLoop, 1000 / 60);

  generatePipes = () => {
    const firstPipe = new Pipe(null, space);
    const secondPipeHeight = winHeight - firstPipe.height - space;
    const secondPipe = new Pipe(secondPipeHeight, space);
    return [firstPipe, secondPipe]
  }
  gameLoop = () => {
    this.update();
    this.draw();
  }
  update = () => {
    if (frameCount % 30 == 0) {
      this.pipes = this.generatePipes();
      this.pipes.push(...pipes);
    }
    this.pipes.forEach(pipe => pipe.x = pipe.x - 1);

  }

  draw = () => {
    this.pipes.forEach(pipe => pipe.draw());
  }
}
```

```
class Pipe {
  constructor(height, space) {
    this.x = 100;
    this.y = height ? winHeight - height : 0; // borunun y eksenine göre konumunu belirler
    this.width = pipeWidth;
    this.height = height || minPipeHeight + Math.floor(Math.random() * (winHeight - space - minPipeHeight * 2));
  }
  draw() {
    fill(124);
    noStroke();
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}
```

**error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: this.generatePipes is not a function

Comment: You have a function expression with an anonymous arrow function, not a function declaration. so it's not hoisted to the top. The global variable `generatePipes ` is still null when you call the function. So either move `generatePipes` to a prototype and use a game instance  or define generatePipes before calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Game() {

  generatePipes = () => {
    const firstPipe = new Pipe(null, space);
    const secondPipeHeight = winHeight - firstPipe.height - space;
    const secondPipe = new Pipe(secondPipeHeight, space);
    return [firstPipe, secondPipe]
  }

  gameLoop = () => {
    this.update();
    this.draw();
  }

  this.pipes = generatePipes();
  setInterval(this.gameLoop, 1000 / 60);

  update = () => {
    if (frameCount % 30 == 0) {
    this.pipes = this.generatePipes();
    this.pipes.push(...pipes);
  }
  this.pipes.forEach(pipe => pipe.x = pipe.x - 1);

  }

  draw = () => {
    this.pipes.forEach(pipe => pipe.draw());
  }
}
```

This updated code should work.
In your code as you have invoked the generatePipes() before your function expression it wont work. Function expressions load only when the interpreter reaches the that line of code where you have your function expression first defined.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it: you assigned a function to the variable *generatePipes*, which means you can only access it once the variable is instanciated.

You have two options: instanciate the *generatePipes* variable before using it, or declare it as a subfunction.

```
function Game() {

  generatePipes = () => {
    ...
    return x;
  }

  this.pipes = generatePipes();
}
```

OR

```
function Game() {

  this.pipes = generatePipes();

  function generatePipes() {
    ...
    return x;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your functions to `this`:

```
this.generatePipes = () => {...}
this.gameLoop = () => {...}
this.update = () => {...}
this.draw = () => {...}
```